# Compressing videos from a smartphone

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression

I have a Nexus 6p with the stock camera. It's set to record at 1080p, 30fps. [Here's](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7j9BuaJzYoiM0x3VHV1aWZIY2s) a 5 second sample (11 MB).

Videos from this phone come out at about 17 Mbps on average. I tried to compress it with ffmpeg with `-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryslow`, the result comes out at about 5.5 MB, which is about 9 Mbps.

I think this bitrate is a bit too much. When I look at torrent file listings, I can see high quality videos at 3 GB in size on average, and if such a movie is 90 minutes long on average, that is about 4-5 Mbps which sounds okay.

I'm wondering, why the big difference? I can notice that my video is noisy/grainy (which is expected from a phone), and that might reduce compressibility. I tried a few ffmpeg filters, like hqdn3d and atadenoise, but the noise mostly remained (maybe I didn't play with it enough). Then I figured, the video is also shaky (which is also expected), and that might reduce compressibility too (and even makes temporal noise filtering less effective). I tried to stabilize it with the deshake filter, but that didn't help either.

I know I could just limit the bandwidth to whatever I like, but there must be a reason why ffmpeg thinks it needs a high bandwidth to maintain a certain quality, and a lower bandwidth would just decrease the quality.

Why do these videos have such a high bitrate? What's the best way to compress them more while keeping or even increasing their quality?

Comment: Your sample has fine detail - the wood grain. in focus. Generally, elements like that will reduce compressibility. Take a shot of just the blue sky and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99.9% of the 4-5Mbps movies you're talking about are `yuv420p` (tv-range), whereas your cat video is pc-range:

```
ffprobe -i x.mp4
[...] yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m), 1920x1080, 16966 kb/s, [...]
```

When I run your command...

```
ffmpeg -i x.mp4 -c:v libx264 -level 4.0 -preset veryslow x_pc.mp4
```

*(`-crf 23` is the default, so no need to specify)*

...I end up with *'x_pc.mp4'*, a pc-range video with a filesize of 5.15MB and a bitrate of 7.92Mbps.

When I convert your video to the conventional tv-range...

```
ffmpeg -i x.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -level 4.0 -preset veryslow x_tv.mp4
```

...I end up with *'x_tv.mp4'*, a tv-range video with a filesize of 4.15MB and a bitrate of 6.38MBps.

So that's already 1.5Mbps less, but on top of that you could also do some denoising.
In the past I've used [FFT3DFilter](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/External_filters#Spatio-Temporal_Denoisers), an Avisynth filter, quite some times with very good results. Today I discovered that FFmpeg also has one:

```
ffmpeg -i x.mp4 -vf fftdnoiz=sigma=3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -level 4.0 -preset veryslow x_fft3d_tv.mp4
```

I end up with *'x_fft3d_tv.mp4'*, a denoised tv-range video with a filesize of 3.35MB, a bitrate of just 5.15Mbps and still a very good video-quality. I can't tell the difference compared to the original.

To improve compressibility these are the options I can think of.

Comment: Good answer, but how did you find this question 3 years later? :)

Comment: @fejesjoco, I'm watching the [active FFmpeg-tagged question feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg?tab=Active) and your (old) question popped up because of "ei-grad" his answer 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

For me the 720p downsampling did the trick.